# Get the Standard Deviation of a Group where the Count is in a Column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to get the standard deviation grouped by year. All the examples I have seen does not involve an aggregated count column.

I want to use the sum of the count column as part of the standard deviation calculation.

```
year  count age
2018  2     0
2018  3     1
2018  4     2
2017  1     0
2017  4     1
2017  2     2
```

The expected answer for the above would be:-

Year 2018 = 0.78567420131839

Year 2017 = 0.63887656499994

Comment: How do you get `0.78567` for the year 2018? Can you explain the calculation?

Comment: @RonakShah The OP is using the MLE for the variance, not R standard Pearson moments estimator.

Comment: To get to the answer for 2018 I just expanded out to the values to 0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2

I then pluged those values into https://www.calculator.net/standard-deviation-calculator.html?numberinputs=0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C2&ctype=p&x=26&y=26

I see when I change from Population to Sample that I get the same answer as @rjen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data <- tibble(year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017),
               count = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2),
               age = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2))

data %>%
  mutate(vec = map2(age, count, ~ rep(.x, .y))) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(concs = list(unlist(vec))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(age_sd = map_dbl(concs, sd)) %>%
  select(-vec, -concs)

#    year count   age age_sd
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1  2018     2     0  0.833
# 2  2018     3     1  0.833
# 3  2018     4     2  0.833
# 4  2017     1     0  0.690
# 5  2017     4     1  0.690
# 6  2017     2     2  0.690
```

Comment: Hi, looks like that is it, I get the same answer when I plug the values into a online calculator in sample mode rather than population.